# Angular 2 ADAL doesn't refresh after an hour

Tags: angularjs, adal, adal.js

My app component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();
    this.adalService.getUser();
}
constructor(
    private adalService: AdalService,
    private secretService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
private appinsightsService: AppInsightsService, 
@Inject('AiKey') private applicationInsightsKey: any
) {
this.appinsightsService.Init({
        instrumentationKey: applicationInsightsKey
    });
    this.adalService.init(this.secretService.adalConfig);
}
}
```

My login component:

```
export class LoginComponent {
model: any = {};
loading = false;
error = '';

constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AdalService) {
    if (this.authenticationService.userInfo.isAuthenticated) {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
    } else {
        this.authenticationService.login();
    }
}

login() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService.login();
}
}
```

My router:

```
export const router: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [LoggedInGuard] },
{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
},
{
    path: 'unauthorized',
    component: UnauthorizedComponent
},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(router);
```

My login guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoggedInGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(private adalService: AdalService,
    private router: Router) {
}

canActivate() {
    if (this.adalService.userInfo.isAuthenticated) {
        var roles = this.adalService.userInfo.profile.roles as Array<string>;
        if (roles != undefined && roles.some(x => x === "user")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/unauthorized']);
            return false;
        }
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
}
}
```

The issue I am having is that I can successfully authorize the user and use the APIs that are protected. After an hour, the token expires and the library attempts to refresh it on the next network request, it attempts an iframe refresh but it doesn't appear to update the local storage with the new access token.

Comment: The code above doesn't show the code how you refresh the access token.  Would you mind sharing the code that trigger the refresh request?